# Writing a Background Message Service for .NET MAUI Blazor App IOS

Tags: ios, backgroundworker, maui

I try to program an application for Apple IOS. I use a .NET MAUI Blazor App for this project, because our whole development is in C#.
What I want to do:
I want to receive messages from a MQTT Server. Therefore I use MQTTnet and subscribe the topics I need.
If a message is received I want to send a local push notification with some information.
My problem is:
I need an service, task, thread or something like this. To listen to the topics from the MQTT Server which is always active!

I tried:
Background Task from UIApplication
Events like DidEnterBackground and Foreground
etc.

Comment: This just isn't possible on iOS.  Tasks that are suspended (not on screen) can't listen for network packets.  A better architecture is to have a server task that is subscribed to the MQTT topics and which sends push notifications to the mobile device.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Can you tell me how this works?

Comment: You can search for details on remote notifications, but essentially when your app starts you get given a remote notification identifier.  You need to store this value on your server.  Your server would then listen for MQTT events and send push notifications via the Apple service to the device notification identifiers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:
As @paulw11 said, it is not possible to run a background service for a long time. We have to send the Notifications via APN Servers. You can Prepare a Worker Service which is subscribing every topic and with the NuGet Package "PushNotifications.Server.AspNetCore" you can prepare a Message, but you need the permission of the user to end them messages and a token from the device. If he has Given the permission, you can get the token from the following code in the AppDelegate.cs

```html
public virtual void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIKit.UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
        {
            byte[] result = new byte[deviceToken.Length];
            Marshal.Copy(deviceToken.Bytes, result, 0, (int)deviceToken.Length);
            var token = BitConverter.ToString(result).Replace("-", "");
        }
```

Again Thanks to @paulw11